# failing on unknown properties w/notification

Tags: java, jackson

If I disable failure on unknown properties:

`new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)`

is there a way to be notified when an unknown property is encountered? So that I can output a log message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DeserializationProblemHandler`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/DeserializationProblemHandler.html) class seems to do what you want.

It allows you to implement this method to handle unknown properties:

```
boolean handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext ctxt,
        JsonParser jp, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer,
        Object beanOrClass, String propertyName)
```

According to the documentation:

> Method called when a JSON Map ("Object") entry with an unrecognized
>   name is encountered.

You can register your custom handler on your `DeserializationConfig` object using the [`DeserializationConfig.withHandler(DeserializationProblemHandler h)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationConfig.html#withHandler(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler)) method.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc of [`DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) says:

> Feature that determines whether encountering of unknown properties (ones that do not map to a property, and **there is no** "any setter" or **handler that can handle it**) should result in a failure (by throwing a JsonMappingException) or not.

The keyword here is "handler", so looking for handlers, you'll find method [`DeserializationConfig.withHandler(DeserializationProblemHandler h)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationConfig.html#withHandler-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler-), and javadoc of [`DeserializationProblemHandler`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/DeserializationProblemHandler.html) says:

> This is the class that can be registered (via `DeserializationConfig` object owner by `ObjectMapper`) to get called when a potentially recoverable problem is encountered during deserialization process. **Handlers can try to resolve the problem, throw an exception or do nothing.**

In your case, you want to log the problem, then "do nothing".

So, a little *research* of the javadoc provided an answer to you question.